# react-router-dom Link tag not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm very new to React. I'm trying to get basic routing working with react-router-dom (v.4.0.0) but I cannot get the Link tag to work. The URL changes but the component linked to does not get rendered. No errors in the console. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the code I have.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

class First extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>First</div>);
  }
}

class Second extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>Second</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Welcome</p>
          <Link to="/first">1</Link>
          <Link to="/second">2</Link>
        </div>
        <Route path="/first" component={First} />
        <Route path="/second" component={Second} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: if I remove the middleware/redux stuff, it works. But I need redux. Any ideas how to make this work with redux code there?

Answer (score 1):

Add base route as well:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route path="/" component={() => (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome</p>
        <Link to="/first">1</Link>
        <Link to="/second">2</Link>
      </div>
    )} />
    <Route path="/first" component={First} />
    <Route path="/second" component={Second} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This exact thing didn't work, but adding Switch around the route definitions did! thanks!

...
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={() => (
                    <div>
                        <p>Welcome</p>
                        <Link to="/first">1</Link>
                        <Link to="/second">2</Link>
                    </div>
                )} />
                <Route path='/first' component={First}/>
                <Route path='/second' component={Second}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>